# Difference between event.target.value and (event, value)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm quite new to react and its hooks, but I had an application where I used this hook:
`const [fileType, setFileType] = useState('')`
Then in the code, I have a select dropdown box where the user can pick a type of file.
my onChange function is defined as such:

```
const handleSelectFileType = (event) => {
  setFileType(event.target.value)
}
```

When I did this, the page was unable to detect change in fileType, despite me clicking it repeatedly. However, when I changed the code to

```
const handleSelectFileType = (event, value) => {
  setFileType(value)
}
```

then suddenly it worked, and react was able to detect change in the fileType.
I was wondering what is the difference between these 2, as I thought they behaved the same way, but clearly not.

This is how I use handleSelectFileType:

```
<AutocompleteForm array={files} label="File type" onChange={handleSelectFileType} />
```

where `files = ["image", "text"]`
and AutocompleteForm is a component defined as follows:

```
export default function AutocompleteForm(props) {
  const { label, array, onChange} = props
  
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      //id="combo-box-demo"
      options={array}
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={label}
       />}
       onChange={onChange}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you share how you're using `handleSelectFileType`?

Comment: @NickParsons Of course, I've updated the question to contain how I use handleSelectFileType.

Comment: It basically depends on how the Autocomplete component is defined. Internally it will call the handleSelectFileType function and pass arguments to it. In this case it looks like the second argument is the value, but that’s not the case for all onChange callbacks.